# PHP How to fix Notice: Undefined variable method PDO::fetchAll()

Tags: php

i have this problem with PDO select.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web", "root", "");

$result = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name, place, add FROM system_tab"');
$result->execute();

$result = $db->fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['last_name'];
}

$db = null;
```

Ive got this error, thanks for help.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetchAll() in

Comment: Read the examples in the PDO manual, or any PDO tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code ... Actually you are trying to call fetchAll method to the db object but this fetchAll method should be applied to statement that holds the executed query pointer. So it should be as below.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web", "root", "");
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name, place, add FROM system_tab"');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['last_name'];
}
```

I hope this will help you , Feel free to comment.

Comment: What was wrong and how did you fix it - that's what's missing in your answer to make it a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch `$result` not `$db`.

Try this :

```
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name, place, add FROM system_tab"');
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 echo $row['first_name'];
 echo $row['last_name'];
}
```